# Sockets - time out

Tags: php, sockets, centos

im trying to connect to a wsdl service , 
but getting this error:

wsdl error: Getting http://api.didww.com/api/?wsdl - HTTP ERROR: socket read of headers timed out

locally there is no problem, but on the remote server i get this error.

remote server: Linux CentOS (FreePBX)

the code:

```
$client = new soapclient($site, true);
$err = $client->getError();
if ($err)
{
    echo 'ERROR: ' . $err . '</pre>';
}

$username = 'XXXX';
$_key = 'YYYY';
$auth_string = sha1($username.$_key);

$arr = array();
$arr[0] = $auth_string;
$arr[1] = $country_id;

$result = $client->call('getcities', $arr);

if ($client->fault)
{
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($result);
    echo '</pre>';
}
else
{
    $err = $client->getError();
    if ($err)
    {
        echo 'Error: <pre>' . $err . '</pre>';
    }
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Are you sure its not firewall related? Have you tried to connect to the target server in another way?

Comment: I shut down the firewall, still same problem.

Comment: what is your timeout setting for "default_socket_timeout"?

Comment: Can you fetch data from any http source on that server, like e.g. `<?php $c = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com');` ?

Comment: check php.ini or use
$setting = ini_get('default_socket_timeout');

also you can try to set conn timeout and resp timeout with soapclient parameters

Comment: And does it also work with `<?php $c=file_get_contents('http://api.didww.com'); echo gettype($c);` ? (I get an "403 forbidden" but at least it's something other than "time out"...)

Comment: "new soapclient()" - according to the error message this class is not provided by PHP's soap extension but by nuSOAP as in http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/ , right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default socket timeout is set in ini  so you can just increase it and see if it works then

```
ini_set('default_socket_timeout', 160);
```

Or you can pass it as a constructor parameter (option)  to soapclient

```
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("connection_timeout"=>15));
```

Comment: its working , but the problem is that it takes ages to load, 1:30 avg, 

and on the local server, and other servers, few mili seconds. what could be the problem?